I am looking for a mechanism the will allow a rope to be pulled out and stay in one place then with a lug will be retracted back into the container
So what i mean is kind of like a dog leash where you can pull it out and click the button in to stop it then when you release the button it gets pulled back in. I need something like this for a project I am working on but I dont want the the button. I want it to be pulled out to a specific length then when I want it back in the container I just give it a tug a few inches past that point.

this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=auto+retract+power+cord&iax=images&ia=images

Look at the coiling mechanism on most vacuum cleaners with retractable cords.  Its also the same mechanism you will find in pull down protector screen, and some wind screens.

Also look at measuring tapes used by builders & carpenters.

Look at venetian blind mechanism for raising and lowering the blind.
